# Restrict selectable credentials when using Git plugin options

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins instance that has users on different projects.  I also have a Bitbucket instance where the users store their code.  Push/pull access to the code repositories is authenticated by SSH public/private keys.  Not all users in Bitbucket have access to all repositories.

I want users to be able to configure their jobs to use their own private keys to pull source from Bitbucket, but users should not be able to access other users' private keys.  Is this possible with combination of the Jenkins Credentials plugin and the Git plugin?  If so, how do I configure this?

If this is not possible with the Jenkins Credentials plugin/Git plugin, how can I implement this in Jenkins?  I figure enterprises that use Jenkins must have resolved this problem but I can't find a solution anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins has a lot of inherent security issues in this respect and allowing users to have configuration permissions in a multi-tenant environment is very difficult to lock down.

Even if you were able to set permissions on a per credentials basis, a user that has configuration permissions to setup their own freestyle job can easily run processes on the nodes that could scrape passwords from the environment of other tenants. This can even be done with background processes if you limit one executor slot per node.

From what I've seen in industry and leveraged myself for an enterprise scale there are two high-level recommendations I would suggest:

1. Breakup the single instance into multiple instances so each set of
   users or teams can have their own instance to work with.
2. Evaluate what users' functional needs are and provide a capability to request jobs where configuration permissions do not need to be given to users, rather only build/read permissions.

**For Item 1:**

Breaking up the instances not only helps Jenkins management from a security perspective, but from a scaling perspective as well since there are several issues you can run into with Jenkins once reaching a certain size (e.g. users that are resource hogs, unstashing bottlenecks, archiving bottlenecks, poorly written pipelines, etc.). These scaling problems typically lead to a need of vertically scaling the Jenkins master.

However, this approach has its own set of issues to solve since you now have multiple instances to maintain, but that is typically a bit easier to manage and there are some off-the-shelf solutions available if you're willing to pay the price (e.g. [Cloudbees CI](https://www.cloudbees.com/products/continuous-integration)). Managing multiple instances can be solved in-house as well if you're willing to write some scripts or setup a service to handle this. Personally I'm a bit more of a fan of the in-house solution than the paid solution since I lean towards the ability to control one's own destiny and off-the-shelf solutions aren't always the one-size-fits-all they claim to be.

**For Item 2:**

If you really want to keep a single instance, the best way to secure it is to not let users have configuration permissions. As mentioned above, Jenkins has a lot of inherent security issues that does not make it well-suited for users to configure jobs in a multi-tenant setting. By evaluating the users' needs, you often find that there is a lot of common requirements users have that could be provided from common job templates without having to give them permissions.

Leveraging the [Job DSL plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl/) to parameterize job creation is one way to do this. Parameters could then either be provided through a custom service or configuration files that are committed to a git repo. Another approach is leverage Jenkins REST API directly with a custom service that posts new job configurations from a customs job templates.

However, this approach could still run into scaling problem in the long term if the utilization of the Jenkins instance is expected to increase. These scaling problem are not insurmountable and can be mitigated with vertical scaling or offloading some stashing/archiving activity, but eventually at a certain point it might make sense to re-evaluate going with Item 1, or even a combination of Item 1 with Item 2.

**Conclusion:**

I know this is not likely the answer you were hoping for, but if security is a major concern, then a multi-tenant Jenkins instance that allow users' configuration permissions is not they way to go.

Comment: You're correct in that this is not a useful answer for me.

Comment: @Rossman If you want to hide the credentials, you're limited to going into one of those directions for the most part. Otherwise the credentials can be exposed by users that aren't intended to have access to those repositories.

The point is even if you could add per user permissions to the credentials, unauthorized users can still access them.

If the honor system is sufficient and security isn't a concern, then there shouldn't be the need for multiple ssh key pairs and you should be able to just leverage a single key pair for simplicity.

Comment: @Rossman You're question was looking for how enterprises have solved this, and I have given you two different ways in which this has been solved from a security perspective at enterprise scale. This isn't for small companies either, but for large tech.

Comment: @Hazon "The point is even if you could add per user permissions to the credentials, unauthorized users can still access them." Please point to some documentation supporting this.

Comment: @Roffman Ask a separate question if that's what you're looking for. Here is one example from Jenkins documentation which states, "so you should not run a job which uses secrets on the same node as a job controlled by untrusted parties." This is essentially a mutli-tenant environment where you don't want one tenant to have access to either global secrets or another tenants secrets. There are other ways to attack that as well depending upon the Jenkins setup.

Comment: That is why my answer is in reference to the direction enterprises have taken, which as you said in your question you "figure enterprises" had a solve, and they do, just not the one you had in mind because of the issues already stated.

Comment: "so you should not run a job which uses secrets on the same node as a job controlled by untrusted parties."  Which is why they recommend running jobs on slave nodes instead of all on a single master node.  This does not support your claim that Jenkins is not suitable for multi-tenant paradigms.

Comment: @Rossman They are referring to Jenkins agents/nodes, not the master.

Comment: @Rossman I have done this hack myself and received a bug bounty for it. It can be done.